# html table miss their border color and background color after print

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, printing

```
<input type= "button" value="Print"  onclick="return PrintReport()" class="lbutton"/>
 <iframe frameborder="0" height="768px" width="95%" id="loader" src="" name="loader"/>
 function PrintReport()
        {
            document.getElementById('loader').contentWindow.document.execCommand('Print',false,null);
            return false;
         }
```

iframe name loader containing aspx page(html table report)

on click of button **print is sucess** but when i preview in pdf format.

then **html report misses their border color and background color**.

i check settings in ie 8 allow background color and images.

How i get table border color and background color after print.

Comment: Give inline CSS to your table and then check it.

Comment: giv inline CSS but not apply back ground color after print

Comment: in ie 7 is working correct but fail in ie 8

Comment: then waht is above code or what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using inline CSS for border color.

```
style="border: 5px solid #333"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate your scenario to be sure, but I've had many style issues occur when I've inadvertently "self closed" an iframe element. It is not a self closing element. It's worth trying...

Instead of :

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" height="768px" width="95%" id="loader" src="" name="loader"/>
```

Do this:

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" height="768px" width="95%" id="loader" src="" name="loader"></iframe>
```